# Animacion en CSS

Tags: html, css, diseño

Estoy diseñando un boton en CSS, lo que hago es que cuando el mouse este encima del elemento, este se agrande un poco con TRANSICION:300MS para que no se agrande bruscamente, asi de la nada.Pero al salir del mouse encima del elemento este efecto se quita bruscamente, quisiera saber como hacer ese detalle?

Comment: podrias poner el codigo que tienes pleas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé qué código tienes, pero quizá hayas puesto la transición en el `:hover` y debería estar en el elemento básico. Si lo pones solo en el hover, no funcionará a la vuelta, que es lo que estás describiendo.

```css
div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #aaa;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 4px;
  transition: 300ms;
  width: 80px;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>Elemento</div>
```

Comment: Brother, me has ayudado, te agradezco brutalmente. Le atinaste a mi inconveniente.

Comment: @AlexAlarcon las respuestas que son útiles a las preguntas deben ser aceptadas para que la comunidad lo sepa y así también reconozces el esfuerzo y tiempo que te han brindado con ellas. Pulsa sobre este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas y léete el [tour] para aprender bien el funcionamiento del sitio, gracias.